# MySQL query fail

Tags: php, mysql

I made a function inside a class called `premium`, but I got this error

```
MySQL Query fail: SELECT * FROM downloads ORDER BY id DESC
```

The function:

```
public function use_prem(){

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wcddl_downloads ORDER BY id DESC";

$fetch_like = $this->fetch_all_array($sql);
if($this->affected_rows < 0){
  echo 'No entries ';
}
else {
  foreach($fetch_like as $down_like){

  $sql_star = "SELECT * FROM like WHERE download_id='$down_like[id]'";
  $row_star = $this->query_first($sql_star);

  echo '<br /><a href="#" class="favorite" id="'.$down_like['id'].'" />';
    if($down_like['id']!=$row_star['download_id']) {
      echo '<img align=\"mezo\" src="../images/star_grey.png"/>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<img src="../images/star.png"/>';
    }
  echo '</a></div>';

  }

}

}

return true;            
}
```

The code works well if used outside this class, but not when used as shown.  Can you explain what's wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting from mySQL? What library are you using for this?

Comment: Is that really both your actual code and the actual error message you're seeing?

Comment: GIve more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

`$this->fetch_all_array($sql);` (and similar database function calls) look for a function of that name in the class or the class your class extends from. If these are not present, it is likely to cause errors.

(not sure if all comments here refer to the same code sample in your question. if you update your question, keep old code samples in the questions and add new code, as to make it possible to follow the conversation here)